# Entity Framework 6.0 (ASP net core). не могу задать связь 1 ко многим

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Здравствуйте!
Начал переносить проект на ASPNetCore MVC.
Столкнулся с проблемой миграции базы данных при внесении новых 2-ух связей 1 ко многим. Решил освежить знания Entity Framework и указывать все связи явно через атрибуты.

```
    public class Station : IEntitie
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите Ecp код станции")]
        public int EcpCode { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите название станции")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }


//добавляю!!!
        public virtual ICollection<RegulatorySchedule> RegulatoryScheduleDispatchStations { get; set; }
//добавляю!!!
        public virtual ICollection<RegulatorySchedule> RegulatoryScheduleDestinationStations { get; set; }
}



    public class RegulatorySchedule : IEntitie
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string NumberOfTrain { get; set; }                   //Номер поезда в расписании

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string RouteName { get; set; }                       //Станция отправления и станция назначения, а также фирменное название поезда, если есть.

        public string DaysFollowings { get; set; }                  //Дни следования поезда(ежедневно, четные, по рабочим и т.п.)

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime? ArrivalTime { get; set; }                  //Время прибытия поезда на станцию

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime? DepartureTime { get; set; }                //Время отправления поезда со станции


   //добавляю!!!
        public int DispatchId { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("RegulatoryScheduleDispatchStations")]
        [ForeignKey("DispatchId")]
        public virtual Station DispatchStation { get; set; }        //Станция отправления

 //добавляю!!!
        public int DestinationId { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("RegulatoryScheduleDestinationStations")]
        [ForeignKey("DestinationId")]
        public virtual Station DestinationStation { get; set; }     //Станция назначения
}
```

Пытаюсь явно задать FK и связь с зависимой таблице через InverseProperty.
Но при миграции вылазит ошибка:

**"Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_RegulatorySchedules_Stations_DestinationId' on table 'RegulatorySchedules' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints."**

Подскажите что не так?

Изменил:

*RegulatorySchedule*

```
public int DispatchId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("DispatchId")]
public virtual Station DispatchStation { get; set; }        //Станция отправления

public int DestinationId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("DestinationId")]
public virtual Station DestinationStation { get; set; }     //Станция назначения
```

*Station*

```
[ForeignKey("DispatchId")]
public virtual ICollection<RegulatorySchedule> RegulatorySchedulesDispatchStation { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("DestinationId")]
public virtual ICollection<RegulatorySchedule> RegulatorySchedulesDestinationStation { get; set; }
```

тоже вылазит ошибка при миграции

> "Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
>   property 'RegulatorySchedule.DispatchStation' of type 'Station'.
>   Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property
>   from the model."

Comment: Тогда как задать отношение 1 ко многим явно с помощью FK если более одной ссылки одного типа используется?

Comment: пользовался этим описанием http://andrey.moveax.ru/post/mvc3-in-depth-entity-framework-04-code-first-attributes   там где Games и Team

Comment: не могу разобраться что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Продолжение темы с ответом   http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616144/entity-framework-core-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-1-%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC/616211#616211

Answer (score 0):

```
public int DispatchId { get; set; }
public int DestinationId { get; set; }
```

у вас тут обязательно нужно проставить эти значения для уже имеющихся записей в базе, из-за этого и не может обновить базу.

вот так должно сработать:

```
 public int? DispatchId { get; set; }
 public int? DestinationId { get; set; }
```

или можно попытаться дописать миграцию с проставление нужных Id, 
в методе миграции Up добавить что-то похожие на:

```
Sql("UPDATE dbo.YOUR_TABLE_NAME SET DispatchId = 1, DestinationId = 1 WHERE Id > 0");
```