# Entity Framework Core. Каскадное удаление при отношении 1 ко многим

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Здравствуйте, подскажите как настроить связи между таблицами.

```
public class Station : IEntitie
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RegulatorySchedule> RegulatoryScheduleDispatchStations { get; set; }    

    public virtual ICollection<RegulatorySchedule> RegulatoryScheduleDestinationStations { get; set; }   
}

public class RegulatorySchedule : IEntitie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Station DispatchStation { get; set; }      

    public virtual Station DestinationStation { get; set; }     
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<RegulatorySchedule>()
            .HasOne(s => s.DestinationStation)
            .WithMany(s => s.RegulatoryScheduleDestinationStations)
            .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<RegulatorySchedule>()
            .HasOne(s => s.DispatchStation)
            .WithMany(s => s.RegulatoryScheduleDispatchStations)
            .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}



База данных создается при миграции только когда я явно выставлю поведение при удалении Restrict
OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict).
Иначе выдает исключение:
"Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_RegulatorySchedules_Stations_DispatchStationId' on table 'RegulatorySchedules' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints."


Мне нужно при удалении Station из таблицы Stations а таблице RegulatorySchedules связанные свойства DispatchStation и DestinationStation выставлялись в NULL.
Но при опции Restrict возникает исключение при удалении а SetNull я выставить не могу.
Подскажите как быть?
```

Контекст находится в отдельном проекте от ASPnetCore MVC. Миграции делаю соответсвенно на нем же.
Может что-то из зависимостей не установил?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая ошибка вылазит, если сделать так `.OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.SetNull);`?

Comment: Удаляю папку Migrations из проекта и создаю БД через миграцию заново. add-migration проходит и миграция создается. update-database уже выдает исключение.  "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_RegulatorySchedules_Stations_DispatchStationId' on table 'RegulatorySchedules' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints."

Comment: Попробуйте еще обернуть конструкцию, может поможет. То есть начать с `modelBuilder.Entity<Station >()`

Comment: Не помогло!        modelBuilder.Entity<Station>()
             .HasMany(s => s.RegulatoryScheduleDestinationStations)
             .WithOne(s => s.DestinationStation)
             .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

Comment: Нет к сожалению такаяже ошибка. Пробовал БД создать миграцией заново

Comment: Тогда не знаю(( Не работал с Core

Comment: Попробую перенести контекст и сущности в оснвоной проект ASP net core. и там сделать миграцию, больше у меня нету предложений).

Comment: Не помогло. такаяже ошибка если запускать миграцию из проекта ASPnetCore. Вопрос остается открытым!

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711772/

Answer (score 1):

Ответ был дан на stackoverflow.com: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711772/entity-framework-core-cascade-delete-one-to-many-relationship

> Described "problem" is not related to Entity Framework - this is
>   restriction of MS SQL Server itself. Table with several FKs may have
>   only one of them with cascade delete.
>
> So, as soon as you need both FKs to have cascade - you should
>   implement such "cleanup" in your code. Set one (or both) FKs to
>   DeleteBehavior.Restrict, and in your controller/service prior to
>   removing Station manually find and delete all related
>   RegulatorySchedule

Т.е. это SQL сервер не позволяет такое вытворять.